# Does the following sentence contain a double predicate?

Tags: secondary-predicates

> They married young.

I think it means "They married when they were young". Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're correct.

In this sentence, the adjective *young* is a **secondary predicate**.  It predicates on the subject *they*, describing *they* at the time they married.

Comment: Hello snailboat, please tell me when we can write this types of sentence.

Comment: The question you asked in your comment is much more difficult than the actual question you posted...